# wpf trigger dependency property refresh manually

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have a custom UserControl subclassing from RichTextBox. This class has a dependency property, Equation, that is bound two-way.

When the user drops an item onto the control I change Equation. This properly propagates the change to the other end of the binding, which triggers a property changed notification, but the UI is not changing. If I change the binding to a different object and back it then displays the updated Equation.

How can I force the refresh without changing the binding? Right now I'm setting Equation=null and then back which works, but that seems hackish. There must be something more elegant.

Here are relevant portions of the control. What I would like to happen is for the OnEquationChanged callback to be called after I change Equation (Equation.Components.Add(txt)).

```
public class EquationTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    protected override void OnDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
        {
            string str = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat);

            EquationText txt = new EquationText(str);
            //// Preferred /////
            Equation.Components.Add(txt);
            //// HACK /////
            Equation eqn = this.Equation;
            eqn.Components.Add(txt);
            this.Equation = null;
            this.Equation = eqn;
            ///////////////
            Console.WriteLine("Dropping " + str);
        }
    }

    public Equation Equation
    {
        get { return (Equation)GetValue(EquationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EquationProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void onEquationChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string prop = e.Property.ToString();
        EquationTextBox txtBox = d as EquationTextBox;
        if(txtBox == null || txtBox.Equation == null)
            return;

        FlowDocument doc = txtBox.Document;
        doc.Blocks.Clear();
        doc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(txtBox.Equation.ToString())));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EquationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Equation",
                                    typeof(Equation),
                                    typeof(EquationTextBox),
                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                                                                  FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
                                                                  new PropertyChangedCallback(onEquationChanged)));

    private bool mIsTextChanged;
}
```

}

Here is the property on the other end of the two-way binding. The equation_PropertyChanged event is getting called in the above code as a result of Equation.Components.Add(txt);

```
public Equation Equation
{
    get{ return mEquation; }
    set { mEquation = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
}

private void equation_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    NotifyPropertyChanged("Equation");
}

private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Edit --------------------------

Per the comments, I tried using a dispatcher like this (note that this is my first attempt at using a dispatcher)

```
        string str = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat);

        EquationText txt = new EquationText(str);
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
            {
                Equation.Components.Add(txt); 
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Equation");
            }));
```

but still no UI update.

Edit 2 --------------------------

The 2-way binding is done in XAML

```
<l:EquationTextBox x:Name="ui_txtVariableEquation" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" 
                             Grid.RowSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                   AllowDrop="True"
                                   Equation="{Binding SelectedVariableVM.Variable.Equation, Mode=TwoWay}">
                </l:EquationTextBox>
```

Info relevant to the Components object (with in the Equation class)

```
public class Equation : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Equation()
    {
        mComponents = new ObservableCollection<EquationComponent>();

        mComponents.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(components_CollectionChanged);
    }

    public Equation(string eqn) : this()
    {
        mComponents.Add(new EquationText(eqn));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<EquationComponent> Components
    {
        get{ return mComponents; }
        set{ mComponents = value; NotifyPropertyChanged();}
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string str = "";
        for(int i=0; i<mComponents.Count; i++)
            str += mComponents[i].ToString();

        return str;
    }

    private void components_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Components");
    }

    private ObservableCollection<EquationComponent> mComponents;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class Variable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Variable(string name = "var", VariableType type = VariableType.UnknownType) :
        this(name, "", 0, type)
    {
    }
```

and ...

```
    public class Variable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Variable(string name, string unit, object val, VariableType type)
    {
        mEquation = new Equation(name + " = " + val.ToString() + 
        mEquation.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(equation_PropertyChanged);

    }

    ...
    public Equation Equation
    {
        get{ return mEquation; }
        set { mEquation = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private void equation_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Equation");
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    private Equation mEquation;
    ...
}
```

Variable.equation_PropertyChanged is called when the event is raised inside of the Equation class

Comment: What happens if you call NotifyPropertyChanged right after adding a component to the equation?  That would eliminate the need for the work-around?

Comment: You mean in the EquationTextBox drop handler? I tried that but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Right.  It's in an event handler.  Did you try wrapping the call to NotifyPropertyChanged in an asynchronous dispatcher?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with those. I'll look it up and give it a try.

Comment: See my edit. Still no luck (assuming I did it correctly)

Comment: Make sure your binding source actually implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  I had a colleague who spent hours debugging a data-binding issue because he implemented the `PropertyChanged` event but forgot to add the interface to the class signature.

Comment: Yup, the binding source does have INotifyPropertyChanged listed in the class definition

Comment: Can we see (1) where you set up the two-way binding, (2) where your `Components` member is declared, and (3) how `equation_PropertyChanged` gets called when you add a component?

Comment: I went for the hack: manually modifying the value to force an update and adding a comment to highlight it's a hack!

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that the value produced by the binding is not actually *changing* (it's still the same `Equation` object).  If the DP value *doesn't change*, then your DP change handler will not be called.

Perhaps, in your DP change handler, you should subscribe to the new equation's `PropertyChanged` event and then rebuild your document when an underlying property changes:

```
private static void onEquationChanged(
    DependencyObject d,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var txtBox = d as EquationTextBox;
    if (txtBox == null)
        return;

    var oldEquation = e.OldValue as Equation;
    if (oldEquation != null)
        oldEquation.PropertyChanged -= txtBox.OnEquationPropertyChanged;

    var newEquation = e.NewValue as Equation;
    if (newEquation != null)
        newEquation.PropertyChanged += txtBox.OnEquationPropertyChanged;

    txtBox.RebuildDocument();
}

private void OnEquationPropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RebuildDocument();
}

private void RebuildDocument()
{
    FlowDocument doc = this.Document;

    doc.Blocks.Clear();

    var equation = this.Equation;
    if (equation != null)
        doc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(equation.ToString())));
}
```